# Request is too slow with nginx, uwsgi, django, pgpool, postgresql

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have deployed a service.
It is served by nginx, uwsgi, django, pgpool, postgresql stack.

The page that has no db access is no problem.
However, the page that has some data from postgres is tpo slow.

Actually, db query time is quite fast. under 10 ms.

But result to client is over the 120000 ms

- uwsgi log

  [pid: 2056|app: 0|req: 4/10] 211.207.245.120 () {44 vars in 1116 bytes} [Thu Jul 19 00:53:31 2012] GET /account/admin/cb_main/invitationuser/ => generated 38606 bytes in 122126 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 8 headers in 373 bytes (1 switches on core 0)

My settings are below
Please check my settings and solve my problems

- nginx settings

  ```
  upstream cuying {
          ip_hash;
          server 127.0.0.1:9001;
  }

  server {
          listen  8080;
          root    /home/cuying_mgr/;
          client_max_body_size 20M;
          server_name     cuying.com;
          location / {
                  uwsgi_pass cuying;
                  include uwsgi_params;
                  uwsgi_read_timeout 120;
                  uwsgi_send_timeout 120;
          }
  }
  ```
- uwsgi settings

  ```
  chdir=/home/cuying_mgr/develop/virenv/cuying/cuying
  processes=2
  workers=8
  enable-threads=true
  socket=127.0.0.1:9001
  module=cuyingProject.wsgi:application
  master=True
  pidfile=/tmp/cuying-master.pid
  vacuum=True
  close-on-exec=True
  max-requests=3000
  post-buffering=8192
  socket-timeout=120
  limit-post=20480000
  virtualenv=/home/cuying_mgr/develop/virenv/cuying
  daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/cuying.log
  ```

Please help me out!
It's too slow.....

Comment: Can you give us the code for the page that's accessing the database?

Comment: actually it is occurred in admin tools.

Comment: it have just two fields and have 500 data. it needs 12s to get first page with 100 data

Comment: 2012-07-18 16:34:04 UTC LOG:  duration: 2.556 ms  statement: SELECT "cb_main_invitationuser"."id", "cb_main_invitationuser"."email", "cb_main_invitationuser"."is_sent" FROM "cb_main_invitationuser" ORDER BY "cb_main_invitationuser"."id" ASC LIMIT 100 ==> it is db log.. just under 3ms

Comment: Can you give us the code for the admin configuration for that page, and the model? If the query in the database takes 3ms and the page takes 12s to send a response, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: model is simple. class InvitationUser(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(default = "sangho@gmail.com")
    is_sent = models.BooleanField(default = False)

Comment: I tested this scenario in my macmini pc. it spend just 12s.. oh I have mistake above commend. it was 120s to get 100 data.. gap is 10 times between my pc and azure cloud.. I cannot understand this problem. T.T

Comment: Try to connect to your database without pgpool.

Comment: I had tried it without pgpool. it's same.. I think it can be a problem of window azure. I'm using it

Answer (score 0):

Use `profiler` to find out the slowest point while processing request. It looks like the problem was not caused by `postgresql` or `uwsgi` things.

See [ProfilingDjango wiki page](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango).